# Ajax Not Working on new Apache Server

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have just set up a new Apache2 server on my Raspberry Pi, but I seem to not be able to run Ajax. I think my code might be wrong, but that's why I am posting it here.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='rotation'>Current Degrees: </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form action='.' method='get'>
        <button button='button' onclick='loadDoc(10)'>Move Left 10&#176</button><br />
        <button button='button' onclick='loadDoc(-10)'>Move Right 10&#176</button><br />
    </form>

    <script>
        function loadDoc(rot) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('rotation').innerHTML = "Changed Degrees: " + xhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "run_servo.php?d=10",true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    $degrees = $_REQUEST['d'];
    echo $degrees;
?>
```

When I run the page I dont get any errors, at least none that I see, but when I click the button nothing happens. 
Ive checked the Apache logs and I do not see any issues. For the sake of getting it to work everything is set to 777 for permissions on the server. Any insight into what I am doing wrong or point me in the direction of ideas?

Comment: Nothing in the console log in your browser? (Code looks fine). If you choose to echo anything else in the PHP side, do you get that visual feedback?

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for reminding me about that log. I see that its showing a `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified in the Console Log`.

Comment: Ah. Since you are checking for a 200, that might very well be the answer. However I always thought XHRs would follow until it hits a real error or a 200

Comment: I did resolve the `304` error (see my answer). Thanks for the help i would have ran into this issue further down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Rookie mistake with programming and AJAX. In my HTML code above I left the `form` data in the code.

Here is the final HTML code that is working:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='rotation'>Current Degrees: </div>
    <br />
    <br />
        <button button='button' onclick='loadDoc(10)'>Move Left 10&#176</button><br />
        <button button='button' onclick='loadDoc(-10)'>Move Right 10&#176</button><br />

    <script>
        function loadDoc(rot) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('rotation').innerHTML = "Changed Degrees: " + xhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "run_servo.php?d=10",true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also @Jesse reminded me about the Console Log in Firebug. I was getting a `304` Status. This was resolved by adding `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` in my php file I am calling from the JavaScript.

Final working PHP code:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    $degrees = $_REQUEST['d'];
    echo $degrees;
?>
```